# After command usage in Tcl

Tags: scripting, tcl

So my understanding is that after command can be used to delay the execution of a script or a command for certain ms but when i execute the below command, the output is printed immediately

Command:
`after 4000 [list puts "hello"]`

Output:

`hello`

`after#0`

Question: Why was the output not delayed for 4s here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That what you wrote works; I just tried it at a `tclsh` prompt like this:

```
% after 4000 [list puts "hello"]; after 5000 set x 1; vwait x
```

Did you write something else instead, such as this:

```
after 4000 [puts "hello"]
```

In this case, instead of delaying the execution of `puts`, you'd be calling it immediately and using its result (the empty string) as the argument to `after` (which is valid, but useless).

Think of `[list …]` as a special kind of quoting.

---

The other possibility when running interactively is that you take several seconds between running the `after` and starting the event loop (since the callbacks are only ever run by the event loop). You won't see that in `wish` of course — that's always running an event loop — but it's *possible* in `tclsh` as that doesn't start an event loop by default. But I'd put that as a far distant second in terms of probability to omitting the `list` word…

Comment: Indeed, if we were to ever add another form of quoting to Tcl — rather unlikely at this point FWIW — then a shorthand for `[list …]` would be the obvious candidate.

Comment: Thanks Donal for the answer. 

I wrote the same command as in the question, but somehow i don't get the "hello" print after 4 seconds, instead i get the after#n. However, when i ran your command i got the expected result. Is that because of vwait?

Comment: The result of `after $time $command` is a token you can use with `after cancel`. If you're not running the event loop, the scheduled command will _never_ run. There are a few places in Tcl/Tk that run event loops by default, but the main thread of a non-GUI application doesn't run an event loop. (My `vwait` call is exactly to run an event loop.)

Comment: Thanks, got it now